# Auto Calculate Component in EmberJS

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm trying to create a component in Ember that shows you how many comments a post has. I pull the comments from the API. The problem right now is, if there are new comments, it doesn't re-query the API.

Is there a way to have the Ember component automatically check every 15 or so seconds for new comments to update the count?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Model reloading with Ember Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23372937/model-reloading-with-ember-data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could call a method in *init* hook that triggers new comments fetching and also calls for itself when 15 sec passes.

```
commentsCount: Ember.computed.alias('comments.length'), // Use in template for items count

init: function() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.getNewComments();
},

getNewComments: function() {
    Ember.run.later(() => {
        this.get('store').query('comments', { post: this.get('post.id') }).then(newItems => {
          this.get('comments').pushObjects(newItems);
          this.getNewComments(); // Calls itself out
       });
    }, 15000);
}
```

Comment: this is indeed much better than the solution I provided since ember.observer() is pretty heavy. Also, it does what the OP asks which is to check every 15 s...